# @Asyncronous future method deadlock

Tags: future

I have a method a in class A that calls n times an @Asynchronous method b in class B that calls an @Asynchornous method c in class C.

I want to sync all by Future, but when method b calls methods C.c i have a deadlock.

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you very much
Angelo`enter code here`

Edit

Class A:
        @Singleton
        public class StatesPoller {

```
        @Lock(LockType.READ)
        private void scheduledTimeout() {
        //qmList list with n elements
                    Collection<Future<QueueManager>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<QueueManager>>();
                    for (QueueManager qm : qmList) {
                        if (qm.getQueueManagerStates().get(0)
                                    .getConnectionFails() == 0) {
                            futures.add(statesPollerUtility.runStateComputation(
                                    qm, df));
                        }
                    }                   
        }
```

Class B

```
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class StatesPollerUtility {




    @Asynchronous
    public Future<QueueManager> runStateComputation(QueueManager qm, SimpleDateFormat df) {


            Date startDate = new Date();
            QueueManagerState queueManagerState = qmService.getQueueManagerStateByQM(qm);
            qmService.setLastPollerStartDate(queueManagerState, qm, new Date());

            final Future<Void> queueLocalStateComputation = queueLocalStatesUtility.runQueueLocalStateComputation(qm, df);
            queueLocalStateComputation.get();

    }
}
```

class C

```
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class QueueLocalStatesUtility {



    @Asynchronous
    public Future<Void> runQueueLocalStateComputation(QueueManager qm,
            SimpleDateFormat df) {

            //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you returning in every method when you finish, you should return a Future "return new AsyncResult<>" And for what for you need the Locks?. Try to add the returns and get rid of the locks. if a thread 1 lock B, and thread 2 lock C. Thread 2 in order to return the future to B needs that Thread 1 release B, but B only will release B when C will be release by Thread 2, so DEADLOCK.